# Spring Boot - MySQL use InnoDB as default

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, dialect

I want to create my database tables with InnoDB, I'm using Spring Boot 2.1.3 and MySQL 8.0, so i used this:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

And, yeah, it works, but i got a lot of errors in my console:

```
2019-04-03 19:11:55.182  INFO 1820 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2019-04-03 19:11:55.966  WARN 1820 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table application drop foreign key FKldca8xj6lqb3rsqawrowmkqbg" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table application drop foreign key FKldca8xj6lqb3rsqawrowmkqbg" via JDBC Statement
```

And this one for each of my table:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'test.usr' doesn't exist
```

"test.usr" -> "test" is my schema name, and "usr" is a table name.

But it still creates all of my tables, so how can i get rid of this errors?

Comment: `user` is keyword in mysql can you prefer other name or do escape?

Comment: @soorapadman it happens with all of the tables, i already tried to change the name of this table, It did not help.

Comment: @ED Im not sure can you try just change the property  `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl` to `update` and check  ?

Comment: @soorapadman There is no errors with update, but i still want to know how to fix this them. That's really strange.

Comment: may be look like problem with dialect .

Comment: @soorapadman i can see **usr**

Comment: *But it still creates all of my tables* so what is the expectation here?

Comment: @Antoniossss it was "user" earlier, I've edit this. It creates tables, but also gives a few errors, so i want to know why and what's wrong.

Comment: @Antoniossss I have comment that yday. NOT now.

Comment: 1) I always got these when using create-drop or update. 2) Manage your DB model separately. There are handly tools for that like liquibase.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Antoniossss proposed, I've just used Flyway to handle my database. Thanks.